# how top layout fix in screen when keyboard up in android

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have a layout from buttons in top of screen and a scrollview in below of it.when keyboard come up it scroll total of screen to top and my buttons get hidden but i want my buttons fix in scren and only my scrollview scroll.any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your layout file like this:
In this layout I have defined parent layout as relative layout and header can be define as: 
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

so that it will always be align to top of the screen and scrollableContents can be define with attribute to  android:layout_below="@id/header" so that your scrollable content will always be below your header.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- Header aligned to top -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#FC9"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="Fixed Header"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Scrollable Item below header and above footer -->

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollableContents"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/header"
        android:background="#005" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
                android:text="Item 1"
                android:textColor="#CCCCCC"
                android:textSize="19sp" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
                android:text="Item 2"
                android:textColor="#CCCCCC"
                android:textSize="19sp" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
                android:text="Item 3"
                android:textColor="#CCCCCC"
                android:textSize="19sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i did it but my problem is with keyboard .i want when keyboard up my header dont get hidden and dont scroll to top

Comment: can you share your layout so that I can find out the issue in that